# Countdown Timer in Voice Channel (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a python bot that edits a voice channel name every hour in a countdown and resets once it gets to 0. It's for a server reset at a set time. I have the editing of the voice channel, but I'm stuck on how to get the counter to go down by one every time it updates. As it stands, the bot updates the vc name every hour but the counter never goes down. It's always stuck at 24 or 23.

Could anyone help me out here?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

token = 'token'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('bot is active')

@tasks.loop(seconds=3600)
async def change_status():
    channel = bot.get_channel(id)
    counter = 24
    counterint = counter - 1
    if counterint == 0:
        await channel.edit(name=f"NA reset: {counter}h")
    else:
        await channel.edit(name=f"NA reset: {counterint}h")
    print('timer down 1')

bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1):

because, you are always re-initializing the counter, you can declare the counter outside the function in global scope and then change it inside